# Errors making cairo-gl

Tags: opengl, cairo, msys

I'm building Cairo 1.12.14 with MSYS on Windows.

Successfully configured with --enable-gl=yes, however, when I run make, I get the following error:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Nathan/BuildCairo/cairo'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Nathan/BuildCairo/cairo/src'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Nathan/BuildCairo/cairo/src'
  CC     cairo-png.lo
  CC     cairo-gl-composite.lo
In file included from cairo-gl-composite.c:48:0:
cairo-gl-private.h:250:40: error: unknown type name 'GLsizeiptr'
cairo-gl-private.h:258:8: error: unknown type name 'GLchar'
cairo-gl-private.h:262:22: error: unknown type name 'GLchar'
cairo-gl-private.h:273:23: error: unknown type name 'GLchar'
cairo-gl-private.h:276:5: error: unknown type name 'GLchar'
cairo-gl-private.h:290:5: error: unknown type name 'GLchar'
cairo-gl-composite.c: In function '_cairo_gl_texture_set_extend':
cairo-gl-composite.c:193:18: error: 'GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT' undeclared (first use i
n this function)
cairo-gl-composite.c:193:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only o
nce for each function it appears in
cairo-gl-composite.c: In function '_cairo_gl_set_operator':
cairo-gl-composite.c:387:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'glBlendFunc
Separate' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cairo-gl-composite.c:387:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'glBlendFuncSe
parate' [-Wnested-externs]
cairo-gl-composite.c: In function '_cairo_gl_composite_begin':
cairo-gl-composite.c:751:41: warning: ignoring return value of '_cairo_gl_set_op
erands_and_operator', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-resul
t]
cc1.exe: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [cairo-gl-composite.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Nathan/BuildCairo/cairo/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Nathan/BuildCairo/cairo/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Nathan/BuildCairo/cairo'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas? Configure had this to say:

```
--- The OpenGL surface backend feature is still under active development and
--- is included in this release only as a preview. It does NOT fully work yet
--- and incompatible changes may yet be made to OpenGL surface backend
--- specific API.
```

Is this problem fixable for this version?

Comment: Looks like your OpenGL header files in MSYS are a out of date.  You could try adding in `glext.h` from the [OpenGL Registry Page](http://www.opengl.org/registry/), and making sure it's included in the system `gl.h` (usually, there's a `#include` at the bottom of the file).  Otherwise, the Cairo setup (which I know nothing about) might define a specific OpenGL version token that's restricting the features included at compile time.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Now though, I'm getting a "conflicting types for 'ssize_t'" error. [This](http://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2012-May/023057.html) seems to indicate that this is a bug that has been fixed, yet I'm using the latest version of cairo. Strange.

Comment: Fixed it by adding "#define _SSIZE_T_DEFINED 1" to config.h.